# JS - convert a KBD event into a link click

Tags: javascript, methods

Still beginner here, please be gentle :)

I have a CSS-lighbox with 3 links: previous image, next image and exit. The links are like that:

```
<a href="#img37" class="prev"><img src="images/prev.png" /></a>
```

Then i have a KBD listening script:

```
function kbdNav(e) {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
            // activate link "prev"
                break;
            case 39:
            // activate link "next"
                break;
            case 27:
            // activate link "exit"
                break;
        }
    }
```

My goal is that when the KBD arrow is pressed (case 37) the link @ prev.png gets activated, so that the lightbox image goes to the previous image. Same for the other 2 cases.

What method can be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, select the anchor elements:

```
var prevLink = document.querySelector('.prev');
var nextLink = document.querySelector('.next');
var exitLink = document.querySelector('.exit');
```

Then edit the listener as follows:

```
function kbdNav (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            prevLink.click();
            break;
        case 39:
            nextLink.click();
            break;
        case 27:
            exitLink.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know yet about querySelector. Unfortunately it's not working correctly. I'll explain shortly, after i figure out how to do line brakes in this comments. :-/

Comment: Problem is, there are multiple lightbox pages that have the class=prev (and class=next and class=exit). This method does seem to target always the first one, so it gets me always to the first image. Do i need to change to ID's for every single image (almost 30 images)?

Comment: Maybe a better plan could be to access the image number from the image that is shown in the lightbox and add +1 or -1 and link directly to the next/previous one? But what JS method allows me to query what image is shown ATM?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this topic closed. The solution works, but my HTML was quite messily structured.

I found a better solution with a pure JS gallery/lightbox.